# mysql DISTINCT keyword not showing distinct rows

Tags: mysql

QUERY:

```
mysql> SELECT DISTINCT (stories.id), stories.news_type, story_keywords.keyword 
FROM (`stories`) LEFT JOIN `story_keywords` ON `stories`.`id`
=`story_keywords`.`story_id` 
WHERE `image_full_url` != '' AND `order` != 0 
AND `news_type` IN ('movie_review', 'movie') 
AND `keyword` IN ('topnews', 'toptablet') 
ORDER BY `created` DESC, `order` DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Result: (Notice that ID is NOT distinct)

```
+--------+--------------+-----------+
| id     | news_type    | keyword   |
+--------+--------------+-----------+
| 100895 | movie_review | topnews   |
| 100895 | movie_review | toptablet |
| 100798 | movie_review | toptablet |
| 100060 | movie_review | toptablet |
| 100060 | movie_review | topnews   |
+--------+--------------+-----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` is applied to the entire row. So those are `DISTINCT` rows based on the difference in `keyword` values.  You will have to determine which value you want to return in keyword, if you only want to return one

Comment: What happens if you remove the space immediately following the `DISTINCT` keyword?

Comment: @cdhowie: distinct is not a function. that'd just be a syntax error.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @MarcB It would not be a syntax error, but it wouldn't work either (just tested it).  Apparently this is a T-SQL feature and isn't supported on MySQL.  (Neither is PostgreSQL's `DISTINCT ON` extension.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`select distinct` applies to the row being fetched, not individual fields in that row. Each of the rows in your result set **IS** distinct.

Comment: Is there a way to get only a distinct column? Do I have to use GROUP by id

Comment: Only if you were only bringing back that one column.  Distinct is row based

Comment: `select distinct x,y,z` is basically the equivalent of `select x,y,z group by x,y,z`. if you want to go distinct on a single field, then use `group by thatfield`.

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT` is applied to the entire row, since the `keyword` columns has multiple values for the different rows they match the criteria for `DISTINCT`.  If you want to return one row, then you need to decide the which value of `keyword` to return.

If you want to concat the values together, then you can use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT stories.id, stories.news_type, GROUP_CONCAT(story_keywords.keyword)
FROM (`stories`) 
LEFT JOIN `story_keywords` 
  ON `stories`.`id`=`story_keywords`.`story_id` 
WHERE `image_full_url` != '' AND `order` != 0 
  AND `news_type` IN ('movie_review', 'movie') 
  AND `keyword` IN ('topnews', 'toptablet') 
GROUP BY stories.id, stories.news_type
ORDER BY `created` DESC, `order` DESC LIMIT 5;
```

The data would return like this:

```
| id     | news_type    |   keyword           |
+--------+--------------+---------------------+
| 100895 | movie_review | topnews,toptablet   |
| 100798 | movie_review | toptablet           |
| 100060 | movie_review | toptablet, topnews  |
```

Answer (score 0):

The DISTINCT option removes duplicated records, not field values.
If you want to select distinct id, then you can use this query -

```
SELECT
  stories.id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(stories.news_type),
  GROUP_CONCAT(story_keywords.keyword)
FROM (`stories`)
LEFT JOIN `story_keywords`
ON `stories`.`id` = `story_keywords`.`story_id`
WHERE
  `image_full_url` != ''
  AND `order` != 0
  AND `news_type` IN ('movie_review', 'movie')
  AND `keyword` IN ('topnews', 'toptablet')
GROUP BY
  stories.id
ORDER BY
  `created` DESC
, `order` DESC
LIMIT
  5;
```